# Is there any way to install and run Google Earth Pro totally offline?

Tags: google-earth, offline, mapcache

Is there any way to install and run Google Earth Pro totally offline? Actually if there is not internet access on specific computer and I want to run Google Earth Pro on that computer. What is the useful technique to copy cache from one computer (which is connected to the internet) to another computer. I have tried to copy Cache files to the offline computer. But it didn't work.
Is there any solution?
I have Windows 10
Google Earth Pro version 7.3.2.5776

Comment: I don't think so considering it has to pull imagery depending on where you're looking. If you wanted to bring that offline then you would have to store literally a planet's worth of imagery.

Comment: You can run the software offline, but the data cannot be downloaded for use offline. If you want to see the maps of an area then use Google Maps which gives you the option to use maps offline, but google maps has its limitations compared to Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this should be possible, but I don't think it's an officially supported install method. One thing to check is that you are getting a cache from a machine that is running the exact same OS version, and the same version of Earth Pro. Of course the imagery you see will be limited to what's in the cache that you copy over.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an offline cache from one computer to other.But you need to connect your computer at least one time so that you can install software. Then just copy that cache and copy paste it to specific file path.